# Connection refused to host: smtp.gmail.com port: 587 from Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, email

I am trying to send email using spring-boot-starter-mail and the result is

```
Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout 5000;
```

My application.properties are

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=<email>
spring.mail.password=<password>

# Other properties
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000


# TLS , port 587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

I have tried myriad combinations and all roads lead to this same exception!  I can telnet to smtp.gmail.com 587 and receive a response

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP e82sm2105370oia.36 - gsmtp
```

Many links I followed suggested a firewall might be to blame.  Has anyone seen this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a proxy? If your telnet is successful then it’s using some configuration that your spring application lacks, perhaps an environment variable such as HTTP_PROXY is set? The most likely scenario I come across in this situation is this issue. You would them need to set this as normal for any java application by passing the

-Dhttp.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128

arguments.

Comment: Thanks, Rob.  This is my personal Windows 10 Pro machine and I have not set up a proxy. If I can ping smtp.gmail.com, doesn't this indicate no issues reaching the server?

Comment: Actually, I think you are using the wrong port as you have TLS enabled. The port for tls on gmail is 465. You can disable it and use port 587 or else switch to port 465. See this link: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en